# Looking for alternative of Browser Stack for Web Application Automation

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web, automation, protractor

Currently we are using browser stack to run our web based automation scripts automated using protractor framework. As browser stack is costly , we are looking for an alternative option for browser stack which supports our UI automation scripts. We are ready to make necessary changes in our set up according to new options.

Can anyone suggest any open source or less costly alternative option for browser stack ? TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of pricing, I am doing the same analysis, and there are two paths, either a paid solution/service.

On my shortlist, I had these

- Lambdatest
- SauceLabs
- AWS Device Could Farm
- BrowserStack
- CrossBrowserTest from SmartBear

I haven't found anything cheaper, that is useful, but could be other have.

Other alternatives are to setup either a local Selenium grid or a Selenium grid on the same infrastructure as your website is running on.

But I would expect that you spend the same cash on maintaining your own Selenium grid, over just having access to one?

This is the costs for the various services with unlimited minutes and one parallel session. (Most have this)

[image: Monthly costs]

Note: I haven't tried to use TestingBot and Experitest yet.

But think about how many test minutes you need, and how many parallel tests you want running at the same time.

But if you decide to run your own, then look into the costs of other infrastructure costs, such as CI/CI hosting, Production software hosting. (Unless these are internal/hidden costs)